# How to change andriod vertical items layout to horizonatly?

Tags: android

I'm very new to android and I'm learning android from the internet by myself I want dynamic horizontal layouts. I want items as we use in css flex layouts. I want something like this

[image]

I tried some code with that code I'm getting the result something like this

[image]

I tried this code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:background="@drawable/main_bg_home">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_230sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/home_btn_bg_color"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        app:cardElevation="2dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/wsBtn"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_icon_bg"
                                android:src="@drawable/whts" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                                android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
                                app:tint="@color/home_right_arrow_color" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_60sdp"
                                android:text="@string/whatsapp"
                                android:textColor="@color/home_btn_txt"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your case, better to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview). You can see here a [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/) that how to implement the same.

And for Grid you can use `RecyclerView.GridLayoutManager(context, 2)`.

And for Vertical List you can use `RecyclerView.LinearLayoutManager(context)`.

And for Horizontal List you can use `RecyclerView.LineaLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)`.

Hope this will help you:)

Comment: Hi i'm very new to android can you please give me an simple example of my code by changing my code so i can get this. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Please update your **LinearLayout orientation to horizontal**

look like this

```
   android:orientation="horizontal"
```